# Using test class in another maven project

Tags: java, maven, testing

I have a situation like on picture.
[image]

ProjB has dependency on ProjA.
In ProjA in src/test/java I have some Util class for test purpose. I want to use this Util also in tests in ProjB.

```
public class TestB {    
  @Test
  public void sth(){
    Util u = new Util();
  }
}

public class Util {
  public void util(){
      System.out.println("do something");
  }
}
```

ProjA/pom.xml has dependency on junit 4.11,
ProjB/pom.xml has dependency on ProjA.

When I run TestB, there is excepiton java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aaaa.Util.
So can I use classes from tests in another project?

Comment: You can release the tests from a module with http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html which you can include with test scope in the second project.

Answer (score 2):

To use the test code of *ProjA* in *ProjB* you need to do two things:

1.) Add the following lines to the `<build>` section of *ProjA/pom.xml*:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

With this addition you will not only get the artifact *ProjA-x.y.jar* when you execute `mvn package`, but Maven will also create another artifact: *ProjA-x.y-tests.jar* which contains all classes of the ProjA test code.

2.) Now you need to add a dependency to this *ProjA-x.y-tests.jar* artifact to your *ProjB/pom.xml* (besides the already existing dependency to *ProjA-x.y.jar*):

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- the dependency to the production classes of ProjA ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjA</artifactId>
        <version>x.y</version>
    <dependency>
    <!-- the dependency to the test classes of ProjA ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjA</artifactId>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <version>x.y</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now all test classes of ProjA are available in the classpath when testing ProjB.